# How to calculate Reckitt Benckiser's beta

Tags: calculator, finance, stock, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance

I was trying to calculate the beta for Reckitt Benckiser, but found many sites with different answers. So should I choose the S&P500 or another index?
After studying the monthly price or the daily price?
If possible can you teach me to do it again?
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the beta as [cov / var](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/070615/what-formula-calculating-beta.asp#:%7E:text=The%20formula%20for%20calculating%20beta%20is%20the%20covariance%20of%20the,benchmark%20over%20a%20certain%20period.).

First, you have to calculate (log) returns for your stock and the market index. I chose the FTSE 100 as the market proxy for Reckitt Benckiser, as Reckitt Benckiser is part of the index. Next, you can do the beta calculation.

Here is some sample code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np

close = yf.download(['RBGLY', 'UKX'])['Adj Close']

log_returns = np.log(close/close.shift())

cov = log_returns.cov()
var = log_returns['UKX'].var()
beta = cov.loc['RBGLY', 'UKX']/var
```

Output:

```
0.011709992935796415
```